# OnCompleted calls not tidy

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

i'm new in Rx programming (and I'm having a lot of fun so far ^^).
I'm trying to transform a AsyncTask call into an Rx function.

My function :

- Get all the installed apps
- normalize the labels
- sort everything alphabetically
- arrange them by group of letter (it was a Multimap(letter, list of apps)) and pass the result to an adapter to display everything.

Here is how I'm doing so far with Rx :

```
Observable.from(getInstalledApps(getActivity(), false))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(new Func1<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>() {
      @Override
      public ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper call(ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper act) {
        // Normalize labels
act.setLabel(Normalizer.normalize(act.getLabel(getPackageManager()).replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), "").trim(), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", ""));
        return act;
      }
    })
    .toList()
    .subscribe(new Observer<List<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>>() {
      List<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> list;
      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        Observable.from(list).groupBy(new Func1<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper, String>() {
          @Override
          public String call(ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper input) {
//Get groups by letter
            String label = input.getLabel(getPackageManager());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(label)) {
              String firstChar = label.substring(0, 1);
              if (pattern.matcher(firstChar).matches()) {
                return firstChar.toUpperCase();
              }
            }
            return "#";
          }
        }).subscribe(this); // implementation below
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(List<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> list) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ActivityInfoWrapper>() {
          @Override
// Sort all the apps in the list, not sure it's a good way to do it
          public int compare(ActivityInfoWrapper info1, ActivityInfoWrapper info2) {
            return info1.getLabel(getPackageManager()).compareToIgnoreCase(info2.getLabel(getPackageManager()));
          }
        });
        this.list = list;
      }
    });
```

Once I groupedBy letters, on complete I subscribe with this :

```
@Override
  public void onCompleted() {
//display the apps
}

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> input) {
//For each list of apps by letter i subscribe with an observer that will handle those apps (observer code below)
    input.subscribe(new TestObserver(input.getKey()));
  }
```

Observer :

```
private class TestObserver implements Observer<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> {

    List<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> list;
    String letter;

    public TestObserver(String letter) {
      list = new ArrayList<>();
      this.letter = letter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      adapter.addData(letter, list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper input) {
      list.add(input);
    }
}
```

Everything works correctly excpets for one problem : the observer's onCompleted are called not in the right order. So I got all my apps, sorted by letter, but the groups are nots displayed in the right order (C first, then Y, then M etc ...).

I guess there are plenty of errors in the code, can you help me with this probleme and maybe understanding how all this works please ?

Thanks

**UPDATE :**
Following the advices in the commentary section (thanks people), here is what I'm trying after normalizing the labels :

```
Observable.from(list).groupBy(new Func1<ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper, String>() {
          @Override
          public String call(ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper input) {
            String label = input.getLabel(getPackageManager());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(label)) {
              String firstChar = label.substring(0, 1);
              if (pattern.matcher(firstChar).matches()) {
                return firstChar.toUpperCase();
              }
            }
            return "#";
          }
        })
            .toSortedList(new Func2<GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>, GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>, Integer>() {
              @Override
              public Integer call(GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> obs1, GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper> obs2) {
                return obs1.getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(obs2.getKey());
              }
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>>>() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted() {

              }

              @Override
              public void onError(Throwable e) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onNext(List<GroupedObservable<String, ResolvedActivityInfoWrapper>> input) {
                String test = input.get(0).getKey();
              }
            });
```

But it never goes into the Compare function.

Comment: You're sorting and _then_ grouping. You need to group, then sort.

Comment: So I guess i should sort in the adapter each time I add data, since I don't have all the infos in onCompleted. I'll try that, but is there really no way to sort all the onCompleted datas once I get them all ?

Comment: [`toSortedList`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toSortedList(rx.functions.Func2)) appears to do what you desire.

Comment: The last update should work unless your groupBy function throws which remains unobserved because you don't do anything in onError.